# C11 nested generics

Tags: c, generics, nested, c11

I am writing a math library and want to have a call like "add" which is generic, takes two parameters v1 and v2, and calls the right function. If v1 is vec2 and v2 is vec2 then it will call vec2_add, if v1 is vec2 and v2 is float it will call vec2_add_float. But if v1 is vec3 and v2 is vec3 it will call vec3_add etc... A small graph is drawn on the bottom

v1 -> vec2, v2-> vec2:  call vec2_add
v1 -> vec2, v2-> float: call vec2_add_float

v1 -> vec3, v2-> vec3:  call vec3_add
v1 -> vec3, v2-> float: call vec3_add_float

I did write a small generic code like so:

```
#define add(v1, v2) _Generic((v1),                  \
                 vec2: _Generic((v2),           \
                         vec2: vec2_add,        \
                         float: vec2_add_float  \
                         ),             \
                 svec3: _Generic((v2),          \
                         vec3: vec3_add,        \
                         float: vec3_add_float  \
                         )              \
                 )(v1, v2)
```

For some reason, this works with add_float types but not when I try to add vec2 to vec2 or vec3 to vec3, gives me the error message:

```
‘_Generic’ selector of type ‘vec2’ is not compatible with any association
   30 |                              vec3: _Generic((v2),                      \
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by a peculiar feature of "generic selection" that **all** selection expressions must be *valid*. When `v2` is `vec2` then expression `_Generic(v2, vec3: vec3_add, float: vec3_add_float)` is invalid because neither `vec3` nor `float` is compatible with `vec2`.

IMO, this is a serious design flaw of *generic selection*.

The workaround is using `default` to handle the common case which would be `vec2_add` is `v1` is `vec2`, or `vec3_add` if `v1` is `vec3`.

```
#define add(v1, v2) _Generic((v1),              \
                 vec2: _Generic((v2),           \
                         default: vec2_add,     \
                         float: vec2_add_float  \
                         ),                     \
                 vec3: _Generic((v2),           \
                         default: vec3_add,     \
                         float: vec3_add_float  \
                         )                      \
                 )(v1, v2)
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like "default" solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, `_Generic` is an operator, and each of its operands must be a valid expression, even if that operand is not selected by the `_Generic`.

When `v1` and `v2` are both `vec2`, the `vec2` case in the outer `_Generic` is selected, but the `vec3` case (I presume `svec3` is a typo) must still be valid. The operand in that case is:

```
_Generic((v2),
    vec3: vec3_add,
    float: vec3_add_float
)
```

That `_Generic` expression has no case compatible with `v2`, a `vec2`, so the compiler complains.

To fix that, give it a default case. You could use a separate default case with a null function pointer or an error-handling function, such as:

```
_Generic((v2),
    vec3: vec3_add,
    float: vec3_add_float,
    default: (void (*)(void)) 0
)
```

or

```
_Generic((v2),
    vec3: vec3_add,
    float: vec3_add_float,
    default: ErrorHandlingFunction
)
```

or fold it into one of the other cases, such as:

```
_Generic((v2),
    vec3: vec3_add,
    default: vec3_add_float,
)
```

In the future, always provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with questions like this. That will save other people from having to write additional code to test possible solutions.